# SQLITE/Java : SQLITE_ERROR with load_extension()

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I'm using sqlite 3 and spatialite 4.0 in java program for few months now, but since yesterday, I have the following SQL exception when I try to load spatialite extension with the query : SELECT load_extension('libspatialite-4') :

java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.
)

My program was working very well but since yesterday, "pouf, SQL Exception"
I am in Winod
I develop in java, jdk1.7.0_51 32its, using sqlite jdbc driver 3.7.2 like in this tutorial : http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/java.html  (I use previous versions of spatialite and sqlite JDBC but I have the same problem with the new ones)

Do the SQL function load_extension can disappear ?
If I'm loading spatialite extension with sqlite shell and the same spatialite DLL, it works well.

I'm running out of idea to understand why it stops to work suddenly... so I'll be very glad if someone can help me with this.

Flavien

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in line:

```
SELECT load_extension('libspatialite-4') :
```

You didn't add the '.dll' extension like 'libspatialite-4.dll'.
Try giving full path of '.dll' files or binaries.